# eb create Permission denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create an Elastic Beanstalk environment using CLI. But everytime I run **eb create**, it fails with an error

```
Creating application version archive "app-220526_002612200632".
ERROR: PermissionError - [Errno 13] Permission denied: './NTUSER.DAT'
```

I have looked upto internet and found a few answers but none of them works for me.

Here'the error log.

[image: Error Log]

Here are my environment variables.

[image]

Can anybody help me out with this one?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Given that the "cd Fullstack ND" fails you're probably in the wrong directory for the deploy to occur.

Comment: Which directory should I create a new environment in? One with  build folder of the project?

Comment: Probably in the source code folder or an empty folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the root cause was that I ran *eb init* directly in my home path the first time I executed it.

> C:\Users%USERNAME%\

This creates an *.elasticbeanstalk* in that directory with the yaml configuration file.

Please delete this folder

> DEL %USERPROFILE%.elasticbeanstalk

Now you can re-run *eb init* from within your application directory.

Note: Before you re-run *eb init*, you **must** delete the .elasticbeanstalk folder. Just re-running *eb init* from the correct directory did not fix the issue for me. I don't know how eb knows of this folder in the home directory, but somewhere must be a link.

I hope this helps!